# Jaxb - how do i unmarshal one xml element to multiple fields?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, marshalling, unmarshalling

xml:

`<root>
<element>value (something)</element>
</root>`

I need to unmarshall this xml to two different fields in my java class.

I tried the following but it didn't work. the first field had the right value and the second one was null.

java:

```
@XmlElement(name="element")
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(TakeValueBeforeParentheses.class)
private String one;

@XmlElement(name="element")
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(TakeValueInParentheses.class)
private String two;
```

How can I achieve this without creating a class to hold both values and map that to "element"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may annotate setters and not fields, and then make setter parse value to two fields:

```
@XmlElement(name="element") 
void setElement(String value) {
    // parse value
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(value, "()");
    this.one = st.nextToken().trim();
    this.two = st.nextToken().trim();
}
```

Comment: not exactly the solution i was hoping for but it works well :) ty

Answer (score 0):

i think it's a bad practice, because the unmarchalling system play with markers separators only. You can split the line after unmarchalling the xml.

Why not use this xml format :

```
<root><elements><element>value</element><element>something</element></elements></root>
```

Comment: The xml side is not under my control.